# Registering message recipients at the Application level in MVVM Light from XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

Specifically, in this case the Application itself would be the recipient. My thought process is that this would allow for the least possible linkage between Views and View-Models when dealing with the scenario where a new View would be created: They would deal strictly in messages and the App level of the WPF application would handle these messages, creating new views (and implicitly view models through the DataContext of those Views) as appropriate.

This is straightforward enough, as far as I can tell, if I go into the codebehind (app.xaml.cs). However, I would ideally like to handle this message recipient registration in the xaml if at all possible since the behavior is fairly straightforward, all it would really be doing is calling ShowDialog for the appropriate View (I don't think any further handling would be needed, but I may be forgetting something).

For the life of me, I can't think of a way to avoid the codebehind though (I know that MVVM does not really forbid the use of codebehind and I'm making things harder on myself with this, but I think it would make for better code organization if it is possible without violating some other MVVM principle). I thought I had it when I considered the use of System.Windows.Interactivity and tying an EventTrigger to the Startup event of the Application class, but was foiled when I discovered that it needs to extend DependencyObject for that to work.

To summarize, my question is twofold: 
A. Is it even possible to handle message recipient registration within the app.xaml for the subset of messages that involve the creation of Views.
B. Is this even an appropriate structure to try and apply or am I way off-base with my thoughts on how to organize responsibility for the handling of messages that relate to other views. If it is not an appropriate approach, is there an easier way or a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The `View` should contain all view-related code and no programme logic - this is MVVM separation.  If your view needs to display a message box, this must then be handled by code in the `View`.  This is the same as animation which must be defined in the `View` but can be easier in the code behind.

MVVMLight messages allow a simple way for a `ViewModel` to say "I want to show this" and the `View` to decide how to show it.  The `View` registers to receive the required type of message and deals with the UI part of showing it - be it a `MessageBox` or other.

A purely XAML, and probably prettier way would be to build a custom message box.

As for part B: I would receive messages where I wanted to handle them.